# How to get MarkerId in Artoolkitplus in android

Tags: android, ios, markers, artoolkit

I am using **ARToolkitPlusBenchmark** to scan **AR Tag Marker**. I can easily detect all **4096 BCH marker**.But my problem is i can't getting idea how to detect each **BCH marker id**?

I have found code from here
[ARToolkitPlusBenchmark](https://code.google.com/p/andarplus/downloads/detail?name=ARToolkitPlusBenchmark.rar&can=2&q=)

I have tried to detect marker  in **Markerinfo.java**

```
class DetectMarkerWorker extends Thread {
private byte[] curFrame;
public DetectMarkerWorker() {
 setPriority(MAX_PRIORITY);
 start();
}
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
  try {
wait();
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
 }
 while (true) {
  if(!CurrentConfig.ONLY_CAMERA_PREVIEW){
 long tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
 if (CurrentConfig.USE_ARTOOLKITPLUS) {

  timeNativeMarkerDetection = artoolkitPlus_detectmarkers(curFrame, transMatMonitor);      
  nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.add(timeNativeMarkerDetection);
  if(nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.size()>20){
   nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.remove(0);
  }
  for(int i = 0;i<nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.size();i++){
   sumNativeMarkerDetection += nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.elementAt(i);
  }
  avgNativeMarkerDetection = sumNativeMarkerDetection/nativeMarkerDetectionHistory.size();
  sumNativeMarkerDetection = 0;
 } else {
  artoolkit_detectmarkers(curFrame, transMatMonitor);
 }
 timeJavaMarkerDetection = System.currentTimeMillis() - tick;
 javaMarkerDetectionHistory.add(timeJavaMarkerDetection);
 if(javaMarkerDetectionHistory.size()>20){
  javaMarkerDetectionHistory.remove(0);
 }
 for(int i = 0;i<javaMarkerDetectionHistory.size();i++){
  sumJavaMarkerDetection += javaMarkerDetectionHistory.elementAt(i);
 }
 avgJavaMarkerDetection = sumJavaMarkerDetection/javaMarkerDetectionHistory.size();
 sumJavaMarkerDetection = 0;
}  
DebugFps.updateFPS();
try {
 wait();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
 }
}
```

**iOS**
In iOS i am using **VRToolkit** to **find id of each Marker**.This app uses ARToolKit plus to detect markers on the video frames.

I can scan all **4096 BCH marker** as well as thin based Marker after setting corresponding property to YES and getting each Marker Id.

In Android i am facing problem.

Please let me know if need more information to understand this problem.
I will be much thankful for any short of help or guidance.

Comment: i also want to know the answer. Very intersting questn..

Answer (score 3):

Any reason why you're using `ARToolkitPlusBenchmark` to achieve this? Have you tried looking at `http://code.google.com/p/andar/`

Andar also uses [ARToolkit](http://code.google.com/p/andar/source/browse/trunk/AndAR/src/edu/dhbw/andar/ARToolkit.java) and if you see [ARObject](http://code.google.com/p/andar/source/browse/trunk/AndAR/src/edu/dhbw/andar/ARObject.java) class - it can give you id for the marker belonging to this object.